# Docker: Simple ls command not working in docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM fedora:28
RUN ls
```

when I run the command

```
docker build .
```

I get the following error message:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c ls' returned a non-zero code: 139
```

Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With something as simple as that not working, check your installation and follow the following instructions:

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/#install-docker-ce-1

Comment: Hello. I'm a little confused. Is that your answer to your problem ?

Comment: yes, it seems that I have not installed docker properly. After I did, it started working. A simple dnf install docker does not cut it.

Answer (score 0):

I cant reproduce this error on Windows 10 'Docker for Windows', some people suggest this might be because of host OS kernel where your docker engine is running. So i would say, try updating the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Well. May be, try another docker image? For example, I had had similar issue, but I needed to run some commands from jar file which was is in docker image. I had used alpine version of jdk-17 and even 'ls' command did not return anything. After changing to simple debian-based image it started working as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).